# ¿Cómo separar el texto de una columna según múltiples delimitadores?

Tags: sql-server

Necesito separa este valor en un campo `'data/soft_base'` en sus 3 partes: `'data' - 'soft' - 'base'`

¿Cuál sería el procedimiento?

estoy usando `substring`, `charindex` y `len` pero no puedo separar el campo del medio.

---

[image]

el almace2 no deberia ser A02-061-2_L2 si no 'A02-061-2' aun no logro hacer esta funcion que me aconsejan

Comment: ¿Necesitas hacerlo en SQL? sería mucho más fácil sería hacerlo con C# (asumiendo que ese es el lenguaje que usas).

Comment: Porfavor, cambia la imágen por el código escrito, sino las chanses de que alguien te ayude son bajísimas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para este tipo de *retos* yo usualmente escribo primero un *CTE* que me devuelva las posiciones de los caracteres que me interesan, utilizando `charindex()`, y finalmente sobre este escribo un *query* que recupere las partes de la cadena utilizando `substring`.

Para obtener cada sub-cadena, hago cálculos aritméticos con las posiciones que se han calculado dentro del CTE. Por ejemplo, la primera cadena va del índice 1 y tiene una longitud de `pos1 - 1` caracteres. La segunda cadena inicia en el índice `pos1 + 1` y tiene `pos2 - pos1 - 1` caracteres de longitud.

El *query* quedaría similar a esto:

```
with
a as (
select 'data/soft_base' cadena
)
, 
CalculoPosicion as (
select   a.cadena
       , charindex('/', a.cadena) pos1
       , charindex('_', a.cadena) pos2
  from a
)
select   b.*
       , substring(b.cadena, 1, b.pos1 - 1) cadena1
       , substring(b.cadena, b.pos1 + 1, b.pos2 - b.pos1 - 1) cadena2
       , substring(b.cadena, b.pos2 + 1, 1000) cadena3
  from CalculoPosicion b;
```

Que me arroja el siguiente resultado:

```
cadena         pos1        pos2        cadena1        cadena2        cadena3
-------------- ----------- ----------- -------------- -------------- --------------
data/soft_base 5           10          data           soft           base

(1 row affected)
```

Comment: lo veo muy sencillo pero a la vez un poco complicado por que no eh usado with. solo tengo una tabla y un campo , solo con esos puntos quiero sacar y ps no entendí muy bien tu función, pero esta buena .

Comment: Many, la idea de participar en un sitio como este es justamente aprender. Requiere algo de esfuerzo y estoy seguro que puedes entenderla por completo. Un saludo.

Comment: a si es , estoy en eso, gracias buen día